# TypeScript always uses GET instead of POST while method:'POST' is executed

Tags: typescript, post, fetch, swagger, passwords

I am trying to make a password authentikation using TypeScript and my Swagger localhost server. But my problem is, that it is always using GET instead of POST...

[Image of my FireFox Network settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xav9S.png)

```
function checkPassword() {
    const inputUsername = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('username-field');
    let username = inputUsername.value;
    const inputPassword = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('password-field');
    let password = inputPassword.value;

    const requestObject = {
        userName: username,
        password: password,
    }

    fetch("http://localhost:5000/login",{
        method: 'POST',
        redirect: 'follow',
        body: JSON.stringify(requestObject)
    })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the `checkPassword()` method anywhere? Your image of network traffic doesn't show the request to `localhost:5000/login`. It looks like that image is actually just the page loading up.

Comment: @Ash Thank you for answering! The method is called, when pressing the LOGIN button! https://imgur.com/a/gnYjPDm

Comment: @Ash there is also a network error occurring... https://imgur.com/a/epPHNqV

Comment: This doesn't look like a typescript error and the additional screenshots don't show the details of the error. You should update the question with as much info as possible and reproducible steps, if possible. The issue could be many things from CORS, invalid ports, or bad requests. There isn't enough detail to help much further

Comment: I am sorry, here are images of my Swagger Localhost Server (Port 5000) [link](https://imgur.com/a/FwYbIJ5) and a link to StackBlitz [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yzpu3p?file=index.html)

Comment: My guess is this is a CORS error, not a TS one, so you might require more investigation to ask a new question and close this one. Your screenshots show a URL of `localhost:63342/styles.css/login.html?login=Nelly&login=Jagermeister` which isn't port 5000 and the URL looks to be poorly formed so I'd guess there is more going on here which needs review too.

Comment: @Ash The URL is formed by my IDE Webstorm, which I used to open the page! I am cuttently on the login.html and the rest is made because my fetch uses GET...